# Why is UILabel's text blurry on iPad if width is not even?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Following phenomenon: my text is "Search". I create a `UILabel` of SmallSystemFontSize and call `sizeToFit:`.

The result is 39 units wide and the text looks kind of blurry.
If I adjust the width to 40 it looks perfect.

I read that the text gets blurry if you hit sub pixels, meaning the width would be something like 39.5, but it seems it has to be even.

Can somebody confirm or even explain what is going on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIView` items are positioned by their center which for a size that is odd is on a half pixel, 19.5 for a width of 39.. This alignment causes pixel averaging that causes the fuzziness.

One way is to make it an even width.

Another is to place it by the center at an even point use:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint center
```

Example, for a desired position of `label;` at (10, 10, 39, 19) one could use:

```
label.center = CGPointMake(50, 20);
```

Comment: You tell me if my item is 39 wide and I position it by setting the frame to (10, 10, 39, 19) it is fuzzy although it starts at an even top left corner (10, 10)? That's odd. What's the best/simplest way to fix it?

Comment: This was a surprise to me as well, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: The whole effect looks like a bug in the UI framework. I cannot see any sense in it...

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, you are setting the centre property with a CGRect.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, having set `shouldRasterize = YES` on the CGLayer of the UILabel's superview was the culprit. Removing that line made the text nice and crisp.

Comment: `layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` will only make things look blurry if you don't also set `rasterizationScale` to the screen's scale, as it defaults to 1.0, regardless of whether you're on a retina display or not. You can fix this by doing `layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`